# Steady states and eigenvalues for a non-linear system:

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to understand a non-linear system of equations, and find their steady states and dynamics. I am noob to understanding *Mathematica* (I am using version 6, but I have access to the latest versions in the lab), and I wondered if some kind soul would be able to help me with some of the code.

The system is below:

```
Clear[PBC];
PBC = {
  d'[t] == (1/z) (α - β (d[t]/Y[t]) - γ L[t] - δ ψ[t]  - τ Y[t]) + ε (d[t]/ Y[t]) d[t],
  L'[t] == (j (Y[t]/f) - e)/N,
  ψ'[t] == p L[t] - \[Xi],
  Y[t] == (v + b + α - β ( d[t]/Y[t]) - γ L[t] - δ ψ[t]) 
    (ψ[t] + (1 - s) (1 - ψ[t]) - m z)/(1 - (1 - τ))
}
Clear[PBCSS]; 
PBCSS = Solve[PBC[[1 ;; 3]] /. {g_'[t] -> 0, g_[t] -> g}, {d, L, ψ}] // Simplify
Clear[PBCEigenSystem];
PBCEigenSystem = D[Transpose[PBCSS][[2, 1 ;; 3]], {{d, L, ψ}}] // Simplify) // MatrixForm
```

I know that I have done some no-no's (already edited in the code above I think), but the code seems to work. However, I am getting some problems with the output. For one, it does not solve all the system. I included some parameters for a numerical solution, but even if you take away the parametrization, it gives the same error as it does not solve for all variables (I have more choppy code to get some solutions for a large n number of iterations, I do not get it for steady states). Furthermore, I seem to be getting an error when I try to get the eigenvalues of the matrix. Also I have been trying to put a Manipulate handle on the steady states and eigenvalue estimation to see where the bifurcations are but I get errors.

Any help will be most appreciated!

Comment: Note that `I` is the built-in symbol for the imaginary number, which evaluates to a complex number: `MatchQ[I + 1, _Real]` returns `False`. Furthermore, as you already know it, `E` and even `K` have built-in meanings which might mess up your calculation.

Comment: Thanks! Point taken, but even if all those parameters are replaced I still get the same errors.

Comment: Are you sure your 4th equation is ok? Shouldn't it be the derivative, `Y'[t] == ...` instead of `Y'[t] = ...`? At the moment it is recursive. Stell there is no solution for steady state (`Solve` returns `{}`).

Comment: Please give a minimal example, not your actual code.

Comment: @acl What's wrong with this code being not minimal (apart of possible errors)?

Comment: @IstvánZachar it requires effort to first understand the code, then find the problem.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thanks again! Y[t] is a intermediate equation for the state variables, replacing it in the state system would make no difference. For this reason, at least when solving for the system I should get be able to solve for d'[t], L'[t] and \[Psi]'t and it just solves for the last two  (the output tells me "Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables".) @ acl: Understood, however it will only duplicate efforts to come up with another nonlinear system to see my problem with  the coding for the PBCSS (steady state) and PBCEigensystem, which is the problem.

Comment: @vyperultra fair enough. does this code work? I tried pasting it into a notebook and it gives a `Transpose::nmtx` error. Is this the problem, or a pasting problem? (so I don't try to debug a typo!)

Comment: @acl The `Transpose::nmtx` error is because `Solve` returns `{}` which cannot be transposed.

Comment: @IstvánZachar right. I guess my question is: is this the problem that the question is meant to address? or just a result of a typo somewhere? (which brings me back to the minimal code, since there are all sorts of things going on here).

Comment: Thanks everyone @acl @IstvánZachar! I did include (above) the version which does not feature the parameters. In any case, my question is now whether Solve is a good primitive to solve for the steady states. If I use NDSolve I get the simulations and results for all the state variables, but Solve yields two steady states without d^*.  However, I will go the drawing board to rework the math.

Answer (score 1):

```
Solve[PBC[[1 ;; 3]] /. {g_'[t] -> 0, 
  g_[t] -> g, α -> 0.05, γ -> 0.75, δ -> 0.75, 
  X -> 1, β -> 0.05, j -> 0.45, τ -> 0.35, v -> 1, 
  s -> 0.85, p -> 0.75, b -> 1, m -> 1.2, e -> 0.035, z -> 5.5, 
  f -> 3.5, N -> 4, ϵ -> 0.75, ξ -> 0.35}]
```

returns

```
{{ψ -> -0.527037 - 0.244898 d + 20.2041 d^2, L -> 0.466667, Y -> 0.272222}}
```

so `{d, L, ψ}` are not suitable variables to solve for. In fact, `L` and `Y` turn out to be constants and `d` and `ψ` are not independent.
I think you have to rework the math of your problem.